# How to avoid circular dependency when using page objects?

Tags: java, selenium

When we are writing tests with selenium we usually use POM and if we look at [official selenium doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/guidelines/page_object_models/), page objects return another page objects there.

```
public HomePage loginValidUser(String userName, String password) {
    driver.findElement(usernameBy).sendKeys(userName);
    driver.findElement(passwordBy).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(signinBy).click();
    return new HomePage(driver);
}
```

But usually you can go from one page to another and vice versa.

LoginPage -> login() -> HomePage -> logout() -> LoginPage. This leads us to a classic circular dependency problem.

The only [solution](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/testingspot-blog/ui-automation-page-object-model-and-other-design-patterns/ba-p/992242) I could find assumes that page objects will be created in the tests.

```
[TestMethod]
public void POM_test() {
    NavigationBar navigationBar = new NavigationBar(driver);
    navigationBar.SubmitSearch("123");

    ResultsPane resultsPane = new ResultsPane(driver);
    resultsPane.Select_Row(1);

    int invoiceNumber = resultsPane.Get_InvoiceNumber();
    Assert.AreEqual("83812302", invoiceNumber);            
}
```

But this approach can cause a huge pain in ass in the future if one day executing .SubmitSearch() method will redirect us to another page. Moreover, it is really difficult to understand what Page object should we use after using this method and whether we should use it at all.

So the question is what is the best approach to solve this issue in that case?

Comment: use the page objects when they help... otherwise just use a standard flow of actions/procedures.  You are working with a timeline... not every webdriver action has to be a part of a re-usable class/method.

Comment: For what it's worth I would not consider this example as a bad design due to the circular dependency. The classes depend on each other - that's just a fact of life. Overengineering may lead to way worse / more costly design anti-patterns.